# Node.js HTTP streaming request vs. Express.js request object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sha1

This is a classic tale of "if it ain't broke, don't fix it"

I had created a relatively simple HTTP request handler using Node.js. I am authenticating the request by matching the SHA-1 of the request body to a signature that comes as a request header:

```
var http = require('http');
var crypto = require('crypto');
var secret = process.env.MY_SECRET;

var requestListener = function(req, res) {
    if (req.method === 'POST') {
        var body = '';
        req.on('data', function(data) {
            body += data;
        });
        req.on('end', function() {
            var signature = req.headers['x-signature'];
            var hash = crypto.createHmac('sha1', secret)
                .update(body)
                .digest('hex')
                .toUpperCase();
            if (signature === hash) {
                // request is authorized
            }
        });
    }
};

var server = http.createServer(requestListener);
server.listen(3000);
```

This worked fine, except everything is ugly and there were other features of Express.js I wanted to implement anyways. I rewrote the code as follows:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var secret = process.env.MY_SECRET;

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var signature = req.get('x-signature');

    var hash = crypto.createHmac('sha1', secret)
        .update(req.body)
        .digest('hex')
        .toUpperCase();

    if (signature === hash) {
        next();
    } else {
        // unauthorized
    }    
});

app.post('/', function(req, res) {
    // request is authorized
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Of course, the crypto method wouldn't run because `req.body` is now neither a string or a Buffer. But how do I fix this?

I included some middleware:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Then used `JSON.stringify` to convert the result in to a string. This allows the crypto method to run, however, the hash and the signature did not match!

Is it possible that Express is doing something else to the request body when using middleware like body-parser? This doesn't make any sense to me, but perhaps I am missing something.

Comment: *This is a classic tale of "if it ain't broke, don't fix it"* If only we'd all learned our lessons by now. But I suspect that I never will.

Answer (score 3):

With body parser

```
var options = {
  inflate: true,
  limit: '100kb',
  type: 'application/octet-stream'
};

app.use(bodyParser.raw(options));
```

Then you can use

```
app.post(routeName, (req, res) => {
  let body = '';
  req.on('data', (data) => {
    body += data;
    console.log(data)
  });
  req.on('end', () => {
    fs.appendFile(`./${fileName}.log`, '\n' + body, (err) => {
      if (err) throw err;
    });
  });
  res.end();
})
```

Comment: You should use fs.createWriteStream to write the file if you are using the request stream. Anyway thanks for pointing at the bodyParser.raw.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution. I just created a custom body parser.

```
function(req, res, next) {
    req.setEncoding('utf8');
    req.rawBody = '';
    req.on('data', function(chunk) {
        req.rawBody += chunk;
    });
    req.on('end', function(){
        next();
    });
}
```

I still don't understand why bodyParser.text() doesn't work the same way!

Answer (score 0):

what are you sending in the body of the POST request?

I have signed this string: `nodejs` with your algorithm and the result was: `92FCFCFBCDB06B40F76FEE4E6271EFC2554290FD`

Then I consume the server with curl:

```
curl --header "x-signature: 92FCFCFBCDB06B40F76FEE4E6271EFC2554290FD" --data "something=nodejs" http://localhost:4040
```

This is my server file:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var secret = 'something';
var crypto = require('crypto');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var signature = req.get('x-signature');
  var hash = crypto
    .createHmac('sha1', secret)
    .update(req.body.something)
    .digest('hex')
    .toUpperCase();

  if (signature === hash) {
    next();
  } else {
    res.send('you do not have permission');
  }
});

app.post('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('hey');
});

app.listen(4040, function() {
  console.log('server up and running at 4040 port');
});
```

If the signature is not valid, you will see a message that says: `you do not have permission` but if you send a valid signature you will be able to consume the POST route `/`.